# putExtra Parse.com object ideas

Tags: android, android-intent, parse-platform

I am facing a problem with onClick/onItemClickListener. I have a ListView, which contains strings (saved on Parse.com) "animal" and "area". Than do I have one more string "about" saved there. I want to show the "about" string in another activity after click. What is the best solution of this?

Thanks in advance! Regards and Merry Christmas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your listener:

```
String about  = "content";    
Intent i = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
i.putExtra("about", about);
startActivity(i);
```

On the other activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent(); 
String about = intent.getExtras().getString("about");
```

Comment: `"content"`, is the actual value you have to enter to about